# How can I apply a low pass and high pass filter to a time series dataset using scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, signal-processing, fft

I have a time series dataset with sample rate 1/10 and sample size 8390. I just want to apply low and high pass filters for the first 1000 and last 1000 samples so I can compute a fourier transform without low end artefacts affecting the result.

I tried using scipy's butterworth filter function to generate an array of coefficients 'lowpass' then convolving that array with my dataset y values 'yf_ISLL_11_21_irfft'.

```
from scipy import signal

lowpass = scipy.signal.butter(2, 0.1, btype='low', analog=False, output='ba', fs=0.1)

yf_ISLL_11_21_irfft = np.convolve(lowpass, yf_ISLL_11_21_irfft)
plt.plot(time_data_ISLL_11_21, yf_ISLL_11_21_irfft)
```

But the error message: 'Digital filter critical frequencies must be 0 < Wn < 1' is returned, despite my Wn == 0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I get a slightly different error message when I run your first two lines:

```
ValueError: Digital filter critical frequencies must be 0 < Wn < fs/2 (fs=0.1 -> fs/2=0.05)
```

But I think the underlying reason is the same. When you provide a value for `fs`, the `Wn` parameters needs to be between 0 and the Nyquist frequency. It sounds like (and maybe I am misinterpreting), you want to use a value of `0.1*fs` as your `Wn` value.